# PIVOT TABLE - That gets the grand total for the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the code written by TomT and here is the SQLFiddle: - Many Thanks to TomT.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a87240/5/0)**

How do i add a new column that gets the Grand TotalLoad for the month.

Here is what i am Looking from the above fiddle:

Column Headers:

Month | GrandTotalforthe month | On Peak TotalLoad | Off Peak TotalLoad | onPeak MaxLoad | OffPeak MaxLoad|

Row Header is based on the Month:
Jan : 202.0869+166.6052= 368.6921 (GrandTotalforthemonth) | Onpeak TotalLoad for the Month= 202.0869  | OffPeak TotalLoad for the month = 166.6052 | OnPeak Maxload for the month = 0.9987 and OffPeakLoad for the Month= 0.9956

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your last select needs to use `conditional aggregation`

```
select [month], sum([load]) as GrandTotal,
       sum( case when [onpeak] =0 then [load] end) as OnPeakTotalLoad,
       sum( case when [onpeak] =1 then [load] end) as OffPeakTotalLoad,
       max( case when [onpeak] =0 then [load] end) as OnPeakMaxLoad,
       max( case when [onpeak] =1 then [load] end) as OffPeakMaxLoad
from ReadingMonthPeak
group by [month]
order by [month]
```

Comment: Radar, one more question on this. How do i add another column that gets the GrandOnPeakMaxLoad.Thank you for your help so far. Appreciate it.

Comment: you mean grandonpeakmaxload across all months, as current value is already max in that month

Comment: try this. select [month], sum([load]) as GrandTotal, T.GrandOnPeakMaxLoad,
       sum( case when [onpeak] =0 then [load] end) as OnPeakTotalLoad,
       sum( case when [onpeak] =1 then [load] end) as OffPeakTotalLoad,
       max( case when [onpeak] =0 then [load] end) as OnPeakMaxLoad,
       max( case when [onpeak] =1 then [load] end) as OffPeakMaxLoad
from ReadingMonthPeak
group by [month]
order by [month]
cross apply ( select max( case when [onpeak] =0 then [load] end) as GrandOnPeakMaxLoad
              from ReadingMonthPeak) as T

Comment: When i tried to execute this query in SQL fiddle (link above) am getting an error message. Could you help me.